# What is this 〜な〜な pattern?

Tags: grammar

Today I was reading the story of David & Goliath and saw this strange pattern:

> ゴリアトは四十日の間、朝**な**夕**な**やって来て、同じ所に立った。ー　サムエル記上　17:16
>   Goliath challenged the Israelites every morning and evening for forty days. - 1 Samuel 17:16 ;  (Yes, "<strike>stood in the same place</strike> Took up his same position" implies his challenges from an early part of the story)

Is this basically just a `〜も〜も` pattern or does it have other uses too?  What is its origin?  Is it formal and/or archaic?  Is it a typo in my Bible?

I've never seen this pattern before and cannot find anything on it.  Any information would be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are used with time nouns, in parallel. I know of only these usage patterns:

- [朝]{あさ}な[朝]{あさ}な (also read as あさなさな) - every morning
- [朝]{あさ}な[夕]{ゆう}な - every morning and evening
- [夜]{よ}な[夜]{よ}な - every night

According to Kadokawa Shōjiten "Nihongo no Gogen", it's shortened from 「の間」 ([source](http://okwave.jp/qa/q4444313.html)), but I can't confirm the veracity.

Comment: Would you mind showing us how to read your example phrases?

Comment: - [朝]{あさ}な[朝]{あさ}な - every morning
 - [朝]{あさ}な[夕]{ゆう}な - every morning and evening
 - [夜]{よ}な[夜]{よ}な - every night

Comment: For the record, the のま etymology seems pretty far-fetched, and isn't supported by any serious modern research. Personally I suspect a much simpler link putting it in the same family tree as に and なり(にあり) (and arguably の, but without 間)... but this, too, isn't supported by any serious research, it's just a hunch.